# Can I use regular expressions with String.Replace in C#?

Tags: c#, regex, string, text, matching

For example I have code below
    string txt="I have strings like West, and West; and west, and Western."

I would like to replace the word west or West with some other word. But I would like not to replace West in Western.

1. Can I  use regular expression in string.replace? I used 
   `inputText.Replace("(\\sWest.\\s)",temp);` It dos not work.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

No, but you can use the Regex class.

Code to replace the whole word (rather than part of the word):

```
string s = "Go west Life is peaceful there";
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"\bwest\b", "something");
```

Comment: Looks alright but this will ignore west, and west. And is it case insensitive?

Comment: I think it does the same as I am already doing Using 
    's=s.Replace(" West ","something");'

Comment: It works like string s = Regex.Replace(s, @"(\bwest\b)", "something");. And it works for west. and west, and west; as well. Dont really understand why :)

Comment: The "\b" matches a "word boundary". This regex is case sensitive, but you can add a RegexOptions.IgnoreCase (4th param) to make it case insensitive.

Comment: using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

Answer (score 41):

Answer to the question is *NO* - you cannot use regexp in string.Replace.

If you want to use a regular expression, you must use the Regex class, as everyone stated in their answers.

Comment: +1 only answer that directly answers the question if you can use String.Replace also for regex expressions

Answer (score 9):

Have you looked at `Regex.Replace`? Also, be sure to catch the return value; `Replace` (via any string mechanism) returns a *new* string - it doesn't do an in-place replace.

Answer (score 4):

Try using the `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex` class. It has a static `Replace` method. I'm not good with regular expressions, but something like

```
string outputText = Regex.Replace(inputText, "(\\sWest.\\s)", temp);
```

should work, if your regular expression is correct.

Answer (score 4):

Insert the regular expression in the code before class

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

below is the code for string replace using regex

```
string input = "Dot > Not Perls";
// Use Regex.Replace to replace the pattern in the input.
string output = Regex.Replace(input, "some string", ">");
```

source : http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-replace

Answer (score 3):

USe this code if you want it to be case insensitive

```
string pattern = @"\bwest\b";
string modifiedString = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, strReplacement, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 3):

In Java, `String#replace` accepts strings in regex format but C# can do this as well using extensions:

```
public static string ReplaceX(this string text, string regex, string replacement) {
    return Regex.Replace(text, regex, replacement);
}
```

And use it like:

```
var text = "      space          more spaces  ";
text.Trim().ReplaceX(@"\s+", " "); // "space more spaces"
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Robert Harvey's solution except for one small modification:

```
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"\bwest\b", "something", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

This will replace both "West" and "west" with your new word